# May SYS be locked in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, security, password-protection

Can the SYS user account be locked in Oracle?

Suppose I change the SYS user's password and then somebody enters the wrong password more than ten times.  Will the account be locked?

I don't want to change sys dba_profile. How I do allow anybody to enter the wrong password for SYS more than ten times without locking the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SYS account can never be locked.  It's "special".  In general, you shouldn't login as SYS, ever, except to do system maintenance that requires it.

Hope that helps.